# Issue in reading self closing tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

When using javascript to read self close tag the output is coming differently.

Here is my webservice output in xml:

```
<aryNotice>
  <Notice>
    <PlanStartDate>
      3/20/2017 11:28:01 AM
    </PlanStartDate>
    <PlanEndDate />
    <Location>
      UK / City
    </Location>
    <SevLevel>
      YELLOW
    </SevLevel>
    <SrvLev123>
      Web Services
    </SrvLev123>
    <WebTitle />
    <Weblink />
  </Notice>
</aryNotice>
```

Javascript code to read planned start and end dates:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('PlanStartDate').length > 0) {newXML += 'Planned Dates: ' + document.getElementsByTagName('PlanStartDate')[i].textContent; }
if(document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate').length > 0) {newXML+= ' - ' + document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate')[i].textContent;}
else
{newXML+= ' No end date ';}
```

Output:
Planned Dates: 3/20/2017 11:28:01 AM - UK / CityYELLOWWeb Services]]

I want output to be **Planned Dates: 3/20/2017 11:28:01 AM - No end date**

Comment: `.textContent` is not applicable to self-terminated elements since they have no content.

Comment: There **is** a PlanEndDate tag so you would not go into the else statement.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I expect it to go to else loop when document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate').length > 0 is false for self-terminated element. Is it not correct?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate').length` will not be `0`. Self-closing tags serialize a DOM node with no childNodes, but the node itself still exists and will be found by `getElementsByTagName`. If you want to check that it has childNodes you could use `document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate')[0].childNodes.length > 0`, but I would add another check in case the node doesn't exist, because that will cause an array when it tries accessing the childNodes property of `undefined` if there was no PlanEndDate tag at all in the response.

Comment: To be clear `.length` returns the number of matching nodes, not the length of the content of those nodes. A self-closing tag has no childNodes so `.childNodes.length` is `0`. The same applies for a non-self-closing tag if it has no children including text and whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

**Self-terminated tag syntax means nothing to the HTML parser.** It just ignores the `/` in the tag and sees it as an opening tag. Then, even though there is no closing tag in the code, the HTML parser constructs one in memory anyway. You can see that here:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("testTag"));
```

```html
<testTag />
```

As you can see, the browser just sees this as an empty element. So, when you attempt to get the `.textContent` of an empty element, you get nothing.

Your `if` conditions weren't testing the `.textContent` though, they were testing the existence of the elements:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('PlanEndDate').length > 0)
```

And, since the element does exist, your code incorrectly entered the `true` branch of the `if`.

Unfortunately, even if you modified your code to test for the `.textContent.length`, it still won't work because the HTML parser places the dynamically created end-tag after all the other content, so the `.textContent` of everything that comes after the opening tag becomes the `.textContent` of the self-terminated element.

---

**You need to be using an XML parser to properly access this content**, otherwise the HTML parser does the job and (as you can tell), it doesn't know how to deal with XML syntax.

```js
var xmlString = 
`
<aryNotice><Notice>
  <PlanStartDate>3/20/2017 11:28:01 AM</PlanStartDate>
  <PlanEndDate />
  <Location>UK / City</Location>
  <SevLevel>YELLOW</SevLevel>
  <SrvLev123>Web Services</SrvLev123>
  <WebTitle />
  <Weblink /></Notice>
</aryNotice>
`;

var newXML = "";
var parser = null, xmlDoc = null;

// Create XML DOM Document correctly for the browser being used:
if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
} else {
  // Internet Explorer
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
}

// Now, use the XML DOM API from the XML Document:
var start = xmlDoc.querySelector("PlanStartDate");
var end = xmlDoc.querySelector("PlanEndDate");

// Rest of code is as normal:
if(start.textContent) {
  newXML += 'Planned Dates: ' + start.textContent; 
}

if(end.textContent) {
  newXML += ' - ' + end.textContent;
} else { 
  newXML += ' - No end date ';
}

console.log(newXML);
```